# Units in the ring of germs of a continuous functions at $p$.

Tags: ring-theory, equivalence-relations, germs

Let $X$  be a metric space.Consider the set $A=\{(U,f): U $open set containing $p$,$f:U\to \mathbb R$ continuous$\}$.Define an equivalence relation on $A$ by $(U,f)\sim (V,g)$ if $\exists$ an open set $W\subset U\cap V$ such that $p\in W$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in W$.

Then equivalence classes of $\sim$ are called germs at  $p$.Consider the set of all germs at $p$ and define $+$ and $.$ on $A/\sim$  by $[(U,f)]+[(V,g)]=[U\cap V,f+g)]$ and $[(U,f)].[(V,g)]=[(U\cap V,fg)]$.Then $A/\sim$ forms a ring .Now we want to look at units of this ring.I think the units of this ring are $[(U,f)]$ such that $f(p)\neq 0$.Is it correct?What special can we say about this ring?

Comment: Yes, those are the units. To show it use that if $f(p)\neq0$, then there must be a neighborhood of $p$ in which $f$ is non-zero. Then the reciprocal of the representative of the germ in that neighborhood represents the inverse. The question of what to say is too general. Perhaps that it is non-Noetherian.

Comment: It is a *local* ring, i.e.  the complement of the set of units is an ideal. Note that this (or, an analogous) construction lead to this name.

Comment: I think this should be closely related to a maximal Hardy field -i think definitions vary though. A germ of continuous functions which is, in a small neighborhood of $p$, invertible as a function does not vanish thus does not change sign; Hardy fields are usually germs at infinity ("for some U, all $|x|>U$") of functions with values in $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$. Your set is closed under multiplication but not addition. I've mostly seen Hardy fields of 1D germs. Here is a large reference about Hardy fields: https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.10846 , though they mostly deal with concrete constructions.